# php strtotime with a future datetime returns a timestamp less than current timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp, epoch

I am running php on my server. The docs for the **strtotime** function says that it will try to parse the datestring into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC).

So my test scenario is:

Timestamp for string **"2018-05-15 14:30"**: 1526387400 => strtotime("2018-05-15 14:30")

Current timestamp as per GMT **2018-05-15 13:26** : 1526390790  => time()

Here i expected the timestamp at 14:30 to be greater the 13:26. But inspite of a future datestring, the value is less than the current timestamp.

The server that i am testing this operates on GMT+2 timezone = date('Z') => 7200.
I was assuming as per the docs, the **strtotime** function to return second elapsed since epoch without taking the timezone offset into account. I am not sure if the timezone offset is messing up the numbers.

Any insight into this would be very helpful.

Comment: PHP uses server time. So this is probably the problem you are running into. The first time it converts directly because the time is supplied. The second time is generated from the server.

Comment: A simple test [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/) showed that the first timestamp corresponds to 12:30. I don't know the answer for the question, but I'm pretty sure that the timezone is related to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`strtotime()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended.

From [`time()` manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

So your strtotime() is in GMT+2 and time() in GMT

Comment: Thanks Jari. After adding **"date_default_timezone_set('UTC');"** at the start of the script, i am getting the values in the order that i want. I noticed the timezone diff by the date('Z') function now returns a value of 0.